# Trek Tire Fit Exchange

Tags: tire, size

Can the 700 x 38c tire on the Trek DS2 be used on the Trek Verve 3 which comes with a 700 x 45?

Comment: The cautious chart at https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html (scroll way down) shows some overlap and it wouldn't surprise me if the tyres were fairly wide for the rims on the Verve.  That would mean you could, but you should really measure the width

Comment: Note that changing the tire is one thing; swapping wheels is another.  The DS2 apparently has disk brakes, and the Verve apparently has rim brakes, so their wheels are almost certainly not interchangeable.

Answer (score 4):

Probably.

The most critical dimension is the bead-seat diameter of the tires, which is the same (denominated here as "700", which [really means 622 mm](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html)).

The second dimension is the width. Any given rim can accept a range of tire widths. Looking at Trek's website, it's not clear exactly what rims are on either of these bikes, so it's hard to know what tires they'll accommodate. If the rim on the Verve is carrying a tire at the narrow end of its range, and the rim on the DS2 is carrying a tire at the wide end of its range, then they might not be interchangeable. But I recommend trying it out.

The third dimension to consider is tire clearance with respect to the frame and brakes. Since the DS2 has disk brakes and the Verve has cantilever brakes, clearance shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Tyre clearance isn't an issue because the asker wants to use 38mm tyres on a bike that comes with 45s.

Answer (score 1):

Went to my local Trek store yesterday, nice folks there to be sure.  I explored the question with them, they said "sure, it will work fine", tried the 700 x 38c on the Verve, it was a great ride, compared to the 700 x 45.  The 700 x 38 ride was smoother, faster and easier maneuvering.  Over tough terrain I suspect the 700 x 45 would be a better tire.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to post a definitive answer! We encourage you to "accept" the answer which you find most correct/useful/helpful/something, as a guide to future visitors to the site who might have the same question. It's perfectly reasonable if that's your own answer -- in that case, you might have to wait a little before accepting, as the site doesn't allow that to be done immediately.